# Differentiate between File URL and normal URL

Tags: ios, swift3, ios-extensions

I have an `Action Extension` which can receive various types of files from other apps installed on the device. For this, the `Info.plist` has the following entries:

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>
         SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.bmp" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.word.doc" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.excel.xls" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.microsoft.poewerpoint.ppt" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.file-url" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
            ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count
        ).@count == 1
    </string>
    <key>NSExtensionServiceToolbarIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
```

Here I have enlisted the UTIs of the files that my extension can accept.

Currently, my extension is visible if the user clicks `Share` from a Safari webpage. But I just to want accept files and not a webpage.
So for that I removed `ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"`line. Now I don't see my extension in the browser but it also vanished from other apps like Dropbox, Google Drive.

Currently as a temporary workaround I filter the URL that contains `.html` in the end and show an alert to the user saying this is not supported. But al web URLs do not have these. So is there a way, I can differentiate between an URL of a file and an URL of a webpage via `Info.plist` entries or in a `ViewControler`?

Comment: Look at `public.file-url`. For the full list of system-defined UTIs, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1

Comment: I already have added `public.file-url` but it does not detect the files stored on cloud storage apps.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if in those cases, it's no different than a webpage. I wouldn't expect anything different from Google; that's how they think about the problem.

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, I understand that. I am currently trying to differentiate them based on `Content-Type`in the response header.